# Select a menu item in AppleScript without using "System Events" in 10.9 Mavericks

Tags: applescript, automator, services

I was just answering another question and was reminded of a new "feature" in Mavericks.

I used to have a number of small `Automator` `Service`s that took no input but did something useful when tied to a keystroke. The perfect example was one to bring the Terminal to the front. Some of these required selecting a menu item in the application brought to the front such as `Bring All to Front`.

Now it seems you need to grant "accessability" to every single app so that a universal keystroke will work if the Service uses the `System Events` AppleScript library.

Anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: The fact that Accessibility has to be authorized individually per-app is ridiculous. They need a setting much like the `Allow applications` feature.

Comment: Well, they need a way of authorising the 'System Events` AppleScript library that issues the command rather than the app that is running when you activate the service. But it is ridiculous.

Answer (score 39):

I don't know how to click menu items without using System Events, but if others get here searching for how to click menu items with System Events:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Finder"
    click menu item "New Finder Window" of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
end tell
```

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Finder"
    set frontmost to true
    click (menu item 1 where its name starts with "Compress") of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
end tell
```

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Finder"
    set frontmost to true
    tell menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
        click
        click menu item "Open With" of menu 1
    end tell
end tell
```

You can allow all currently installed applications to use the accessibility API by dragging them to the list in System Preferences:

[image]